# How to create a dictionary of permutation values？

Tags: python, dictionary

I need to assign 0 and 1 as values to keys in the dictionaries:

```
combinations_string_list = [num_list_to_str(i) for i in itertools.product([0, 1], repeat=2)]
all_stategy = []
for i in range(16):
    strategy_table = {x: y for x in combinations_string_list for y in [0, 1]}
    all_stategy.append(strategy_table)
print(all_stategy)
```

I got `[{'00': 1, '01': 1, '10': 1, '11': 1}, {'00': 1, '01': 1, '10': 1, '11': 1}, {'00': 1, '01': 1, '10': 1, '11': 1}, ...]`
but I need `[{'00': 0, '01': 0, '10': 0, '11': 0}, {'00': 0, '01': 0, '10': 0, '11': 1}, {'00': 0, '01': 0, '10': 1, '11': 0}, ...]` instead.
How can I create this kind of value? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can zip the key sequence `["0", "1"]` with each element of the cartesian product to produce input to `dict`:

```
>>> [dict(zip(["0", "1"], x)) for x in product([0,1], repeat=2)]
[{'0': 0, '1': 0}, {'0': 0, '1': 1}, {'0': 1, '1': 0}, {'0': 1, '1': 1}]
```

or

```
>>> values=[0,1]
>>> [dict(zip(map(str, values), x)) for x in product(values, repeat=2)]
```

Comment: Since strings are iterable, you can use `zip("01", x)` instead of `zip(["0", "1"], x)` too.

Comment: Yeah, I was going to use that, but figured space wasn't at a premium here and the list was clearer.

Comment: Hi, thank you for the answer! But I am still wondering if I need the keys to be generated from the combinations_string_list, with the repeat = 2 or 3? --> all_stategy = [dict(zip(combinations_string_list, x)) for x in itertools.product([0,1], repeat=4)] This works! Thank you again.

Comment: It looks like you just want to break each individual combination into separate integers, then apply `|` to them? `dict((pair, or_(*map(int, pair))) for pair in ["00", "01", "10", "11"])`